# GitHub desktop error the procedure entry point discard virtual memory could not be located in the dynamic link library

Tags: github-desktop

I have window 8.1 i am trying to install gitHub desktop app but it is giving this error again and again
**the procedure entry point discard virtual memory could not be located in the dynamic link library**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnN8q.png)

i tried all the methods that are shown in YouTube and downloaded different running versions also I installed all versions of Microsoft visual c ++

Comment: Not a `git`question as it is related to a different client.